# Installation Android-SDK packets

Tags: android, sdk, installation, android-sdk-2.3

I've installed Android-SDK, but I can't to install some packets. For example, I need to install `Android API 4 SDK`, but manager writes to the log:

> Fetching
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
>   Preparing to install archives Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.6,
>   API 4, revision 3 null Done. Nothing was installed.

But other packets (for example, `Android API 16 SDK`) was installed successfully.

I've tried to run SDK `Manager.exe` as admin, but the result is same.

Answer (score 1):

Might just be your net slow connection i went ahead and solved that by installing the APIs offline followed this : http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html#idc-cover

Though you need to get the latest url links to the repository or you will just get outdasted versions.